# Remove rows in @ElementCollection

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name="Something", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="profile_id"))
@Column(name="favorite")
private Set<String> something = new HashSet<String>();
```

I have this relationship in my Profile and it works. A table gets created. When a profile is deleted I wont the lines that belongs to that entity to also be removed from the Collection table. I don't want to use cascading. How can I make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens out of the box. When entity that does have ElementCollection is removed via [EntityManager.remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) no further actions are needed - persistence provider issues delete from the collection table as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code to delete the rows in a method annotated with @PostRemove in the Profile entity class.

```
@Entity
public class Profile {

    @PostRemove
    public void cleanupCollectionTable(){
        Query query = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Something s WHERE s.profile_id = :id");
        int deletedCount = query.setParameter(id, profileId).executeUpdate();
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I remove them? It is strings and not entites. should this.something.clear(); be enough?